# Add two dynamic values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, addition

I have written a jquery script. It **concatenates** instead of **adding** two values

```
$(document).on('click','.woocommerce-checkout-review-order input[type="submit"]', function(){
   var sum = '';
   $('.checkout_ilm select').each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).val()!=''){
         sum += Number(jQuery(this).val());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
      }
   });
   alert(sum);
});
```

When the values in all the select fields is zero then it **concatenates** the value instead of **adding** it. So in this case it gives **00** instead of **0** as a result. I have used `parseInt` and `parseFloat` also both working but this conditions returns true with `parseInt` and `parseFloat` even sum is equal to **zero** and `ilm_selected` has also value **zero**.

```
if(sum < ilm_selected || sum==''){
   //some code
}
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: use parseInt(jQuery(this).val());

Comment: you should not use parseInt().  Check my answer for more info.

Comment: Change your `var sum = '';` to `var sum = 0;`. This should work for you.

Comment: @Rizwi , this solution is helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

I just replace `Number` with `parseInt`, try this solution this will help you.

Refer this link for more information:[click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.woocommerce-checkout-review-order input[type="submit"]', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery('.checkout_ilm select').each(function(){
             if(jQuery(this).val()!=''){
             sum += parseInt(jQuery(this).val()); 
        }
    });

    alert(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.woocommerce-checkout-review-order input[type="submit"]', function(){
  var sum = 0;
  jQuery('.checkout_ilm select').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val()!=''){
      sum += parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
    }
  });
  console.log("Sum: ", sum);
});
```

You can use parseInt() too, but if your value contains decimal for example 20.50 than it will not work, so it is better to go for parseFloat().

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `parseInt()`. The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

```
sum += parseInt(jQuery(this).val());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `var sum = '';` to `var sum = 0;`.

This will help you in getting the sum of all the select box.

Your earlier code was concatenating value of select box which you converted into number to string as `sum` was initialised to `''`.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click','input[type="submit"]', function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() !== ''){
        sum += Number($(this).val()); 
  }
});
console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="20">Saab</option>
  <option value="34">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="7">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="20">Saab</option>
  <option value="34">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="7">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="20">Saab</option>
  <option value="34">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="7">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```